# Running Android Studio app on Device gives me Default Activity Not Found

Tags: android-studio, react-native

I'm currently Android Studio 2.3.3 and S6 Edge to test my app on the real device but it keep giving me an error saying `Error running app: Default Activity Not Found`.

I have

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
```

and tried restart Androdi Studio but error is still there.

Does anyone know how to figure this out?

Thank you

Comment: Can you post the full Manifest ?

Answer (score 0):

Put your MainActivity Theme inside MainActivity.

Something like:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it's inside the application node.

Like this:

```
<application
 android:name="YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE_HERE"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. 1st Step
   Select 'app', then 'edit configurations'.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgWmK.png)
2. Select "nothing" in launch.